# How to use virtual printer with guest WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, printer, vmware, vmware-workstation

How do I use my printer on the host system? I already enabled virtual printer within the VMware Workstation Player preferences and when I start my guest WinXP system the "Printer: Present" button in the command bar is "online", but there is no printer in the WinXP settings.

[image: Guest WinXP]

Comment: Personally I would just share the printer on the host and then connect to it as a network printer from the guest.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: Host is Windows 10 Pro

Comment: On the host, go to Printers & Scanners, select your printer, go to Manage > Printer properties > Sharing. (You alternatively can go to the Start Menu and search for "Share printers".) In the guest connect to the printer via the shared name (e.g. `\\yourSharedPrinter`, or alternatively go to Control Panel > Printer and Faxes > Add Printer, go through the wizard and choose a network printer.

Comment: Sounds good, but I didn't worked with WinXP for years. To share the printer with Win10 is easy but I have no idea how to join the network with WinXP to connect with the shared printer.